# Network Printer works on LAN but not on Wifi

Tags: windows-10, network-printer, asus-laptop

We have an Asus laptop (ASUS ZenBook UX305UA), fresh from the box, windows 10, all the drivers are the latest ones. Connects to our Wifi, and can connect to the internet fine. but when I try to install a network printer (HP Color LaserJet CP3525), it can see it, but can not connect/install it.

When I connect the LAN cable, windows 10 finds the printer fine, and it installs and works correctly right away.

then, if I dis-connect the LAN, the printer will not work. I can see how much toner the printer has! but can not print at all. do not see anything in any logs, I have tried to turn off the firewall, I have set wifi to private. I am at my witts end. does anyone have any ideas?

I have seen something similar to other asus laptops, but only asus.

Comment: Does the printer go into a power save mode? You can often wake up a printer from power save with ethernet, but not from Wi-Fi. Is the printer diver set to connect via a specific IP address? The ethernet and Wi-Fi printer adapters will have different IP addresses. Your firewall would not have anything to do with it if the laptop and printer are on the same network.

Comment: wifi and lan is same nettwork, I can print to same printer from other pc's  (on wifi I mean) also windows 10, even asus.

Comment: What about how the printer driver is configured in the PC? Is it set to the ethernet IP address from when you plugged into the ethernet port?

Comment: do not think that is the problem. I tried to install the printer from wifi, but I can not even see the printer, even if I spesify the printer ip and model manually.

Comment: OK, I will ask for the third time, did you verify in the printer driver that it is not set to an IP address based on the ethernet port. Actually checking and giving a simple, truthful yes or no answer will suffice. You are the one asking for help, so you should be eager to give all the help and straight answers you can. While you are in the printers, check that it is set as the default printer, too.

Comment: I am sorry, I just do not understand what you mean. when I start with a fresh install of windows, I have no driver, no nothing, if I search for printers a) on wifi I see nothing b) on lan I see the printer. the printer is a network printer, it has a lan connection, on an ip that I can reach from lan and wifi...   I did set the printer that I installed to default printer yes.. I have tried to install it like 30 times, in different ways, with different settings.. but I got nothing... that is why I ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. When I connected to LAN by cable, I was able to print on the network printer. When I used wifi connection to the same LAN, printing wasn't able. (The wifi wasn't "guest" wifi, so no client isolation was enabled.) I was able to ping the printer, but printing was not working.

> What helped me was to disable "Block LAN to WLAN Multicast and Broadcast Data" checkbox on my Ubiquity WiFi AP settings. You can find it in Settings -> Wireless -> Advanced settings. Not only printers use this broadcast. In my case I have not seen my NAS in finder on Mac before I disabled blocking of the broadcast data. Anyway it is better to setup an exception for specific mac address to enable broadcast for selected device only...

Comment: I do not have that Asus to test with anymore, but this seems like a plausible solutions, thanks, I think I will will accept this one.

Comment: Same problem here: is there a similar setting in German "Fritz-Box" ?

Comment: I have a ubiquity router and this fix worked for me with my HP M551 - to clarify the terminology of 'disable' in this context (as it wasnt obvious to me) - the checkbox was originally unticked and I ticked it and saved it and then wifi printing started to work.

Answer (score -1):

In Germany, for people using Fritz Box,

> Allowing wireless devices to communicate
> The following step is only necessary if you want to connect the printer to the

1. FRITZ!Box via Wi-Fi: Click "Wi-Fi" in the FRITZ!Box user interface.
2. Click "Security" in the "Wi-Fi" menu.
3. Enable the option "The active wireless devices displayed below may communicate with each other" in the section "Additional Security Settings".
4. Click "Apply" to save the settings.

https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7590/knowledge-base/publication/show/506_Setting-up-a-printer-as-a-network-printer-via-network-cable-or-Wi-Fi/